# pgAdmin III Guru Hint - Server Not Listening

Tags: postgresql, cmd, database-connection

When I connect to default localhost 5432, I get a **blank** "Guru hint - Server not listening message"

Normally, it should show some messages but I get a blank one! 
Can somebody please tell me what's going on?

P/s: I'm new in using pgAdmin III and have absolute zero knowledge about connections. ><"

Answer (score 1):

on what server do you have postgresql server running? make sure your postgresql server starts. on windows check postgre service, on linux do **ps -ef | grep postgresql** or **/sbin/service postgresql status**.

If the server already started, check your DB connection set up in PGAdmin.

Comment: "make sure your postgresql server starts", what does that mean? I'm on windows but I don't know how to "check postgre service".